# Create AWS RDS on specific VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have web application which dynamically deployed on EC2 instances (scalable). Also I have RDS mysql instance which dynamically created by python with boto3. Now port 3306 of RDS is public, but I want to allow connection only from my EC2's from specific VPC. Can I create RDS on specific VPC (same one with EC2 instances)? What is best practice to create such set EC2 + RDS ?

Answer (score 2):

RDS show an endpoint FQDN doesn't mean it is "public".  You need to deal with VPC subnet, security group to enable the connection.

When you create RDS, you must create db_subnet and point to specific VPC subnet. This is the logical network that RDS reside.

Next will come to access : just attach RDS to security group that allow EC2 access to 3306.

Reference : [Creating a MySQL DB Instance and Connecting to a Database on a MySQL DB Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly best practice to have your Amazon EC2 instances in the same VPC as the Amazon RDS database. Recommended security is:

- Create a **Security Group for your web application** EC2 instances (`Web-SG`)
- Launch your Amazon RDS instance in a **private subnet** in the same VPC
- Configure the Security Group on the RDS instance to allow incoming MySQL (3306) traffic **from the `Web-SG` security group**

If your RDS instance is currently in a different VPC, you can take a **snapshot** and then create a new database from the snapshot.

If you are using an **Elastic Load Balancer**, you could even put your Amazon EC2 instances in a **private subnet** since all access will be via the Load Balancer.